# For all $n,k$ in positive integers, there exists $m_1,...,m_k$ such that the following holds

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Let $n,k$ be two positive integers. Prove that there exists $m_1,...,m_k$ in the positive integers such that

$$1+\frac{2^k-1}{n}=\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1+\frac{1}{m_i}\right)$$
Here is my attempt

We're going to construct a solution for the $m_i$'s, but rather than presenting it right away I will take time to go through the motivation behind it.

Assume that $\exists m_1,...,m_k$ such that $$1+\frac{2^k-1}{n}=\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1+\frac{1}{m_i}\right)$$
And consider $$\begin{align} 
\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{m_i}\right)&=\left(1+\frac{1}{m_{k+1}}\right)\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1+\frac{1}{m_i}\right) \\ &= \left(1+\frac{1}{m_{k+1}}\right)\left(1+\frac{2^k-1}{n}\right) \\ &= 1+\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{n}
\end{align}  $$
Where the last step follows from the assumption. Hence $$\frac{1}{m_{k+1}}=\frac{2^k}{2^k+n-1} \text{ or } m_i=\frac{2^{i-1}+n-1}{2^{i-1}}$$
Now we have to prove this solution actually works. In other words, $$1+\frac{2^k-1}{n}=\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1+\frac{2^{i-1}}{2^{i-1}+n-1}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^k\left(\frac{2^{i}+n-1}{2^{i-1}+n-1}\right)$$
but expanding the RHS is not easy so let's go ahead and assume that the above is true $\forall k\le s$ we'll show that it's true for $k=s+1$

$$\begin{align}\prod_{i=1}^{s+1}\left(\frac{2^{i}+n-1}{2^{i-1}+n-1}\right)&=\frac{2^{s+1}+n-1}{2^{s}+n-1}\prod_{i=1}^{s}\left(\frac{2^{i}+n-1}{2^{i-1}+n-1}\right) \\&= \frac{2^{s+1}+n-1}{2^{s}+n-1}\left(1+\frac{2^s-1}{n}\right) \\&= 1+\frac{2^{s+1}-1}{n}\end{align} $$

Now my question is: Are the $m_i$'s integers? Since $$m_i=\frac{2^{i-1}+n-1}{2^{i-1}}$$
Then we should have $2^{i-1}\mid n-1$ but that's not true $\forall n,i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $m_i$'s in your construction are not necessarily integers.

To illustrate the problem, consider the simple case of $k = 2$. You want to write $\frac{n + 3}n$ as a product $\frac{m_1 + 1}{m_1} \cdot \frac{m_2 + 1}{m_2}$.

Your strategy goes for $m_1 = n$ and $m_2 = \frac{n + 1}2$. However we see that $\frac{n + 1}2$ is not necessarily an integer.

In fact, the construction above works when $n$ is odd. For $n$ even, we can use instead $m_1 = \frac n 2$ and $m_2 = n + 2$.

---

This indicates how the solution would look like: you should separate the two cases of even/odd $n$.

We prove by induction on $k$. For $k = 1$, simply choosing $m_1 = n$ works. Now assume that the result is true for $k$ and we prove it for $k + 1$.

Thus we want to write $\frac{n + 2^{k + 1} - 1}n$ as a product $\prod_{i = 1}^{k + 1} \frac{m_i + 1}{m_i}$. As above, we will consider the parity of $n$.

If $n$ is odd, then we can write $$\frac{\frac{n + 1}2 + 2^k - 1}{\frac{n + 1}2} = \prod_{i = 1}^k \frac{m_i + 1}{m_i}$$ by induction hypothesis applied to $\frac{n + 1}2$. Choosing $m_{k + 1} = n$ gives us the willing identity.

If $n$ is even then we can write $$\frac{\frac n 2 + 2^k - 1}{\frac n 2} = \prod_{i = 1}^k \frac{m_i + 1}{m_i}$$ by induction hypothesis applied to $\frac n 2$. Choosing $m_{k + 1} = n + 2^{k + 1} - 2$ gives us the willing identity.

This finishes the induction step and hence the proof.

Comment: I didn't understand is $m_i=n+2^i-2$ for all even $n$ and $m_i=n$ for all odd $n$?

Comment: It's an inductive construction which would be complicated to write down explicitly (probably would involve binary expansion of $n$). Do you understand [proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) in general?

Comment: I do but you're inducting on $k$ not $n$ so how can you say that you're applying the induction hypothesis on $n+1/2$?

Comment: The statement for step $k$ is valid for any positive integer $n$, thus I apply it with $n$ replaced by $\frac{n + 1}2$ which is again a positive integer.

Comment: +1.  In particular, if $k=2$ then $(3m_1-n)(3m_2-n)=n(n+1).$ So if $k=2=n$ then $(3m_1-2)(3m_2-2)=6$, which is impossible for integers $m_1,m_2$ as it would imply $4\equiv 6\mod 3.$

Answer (score 0):

After thinking for some days, I would like to share my observations from [the first answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4475650/89922) and how it relates to binary notations and bit operations. This answer is based on the same recursion step and the same algorithm.

$$\frac{n_{k+1}+2^{k+1}-1}{n_{k+1}} = \frac{n_k+2^{k}-1}{n_{k}}\cdot \frac{m_{k+1}+1}{m_{k+1}} \tag 1$$

where $n_k$ is chosen depending on whether $n_{k+1}$ is even or odd,

$$\begin{align*}
n_{k+1} \mapsto n_k &= \begin{cases}
\dfrac {n_{k+1}}2,& n_{k+1}\equiv 0 \pmod 2\\
\dfrac {n_{k+1}+1}2,& n_{k+1}\equiv 1 \pmod 2\\
\end{cases}\\
&= \left\lfloor\frac{n_{k+1}+1}2\right\rfloor
= \left\lceil\frac{n_{k+1}}2\right\rceil  \tag2
\end{align*}$$

---

From $n_{k+1}+2^{k+1}-1$ to $n_k+2^k-1$ in the numerators of $(1)$ is actually simple: it's a floored division by $2$, or a right shift by $1$ bit:

$$\begin{align*}
n_k+2^k-1 &= \left\lfloor\frac{n_{k+1}+1}2\right\rfloor + 2^k-1\\
&= \left\lfloor\frac{n_{k+1}+1}2 +2^k-1\right\rfloor\\
&= \left\lfloor\frac{n_{k+1}+2^{k+1}-1}2\right\rfloor
\end{align*}$$

But from $n_{k+1}$ to  $n_k$ in the denominators is less obvious.
Applying $(2)$ is not simply a floored division nor a right shift by $1$ bit. Repeated application of $(2)$ to a positive $n$ will also never get to $0$. But there's still some pattern, by noting the parity of $n \pmod 2$ at each step, for example when applying to $n=10$,

$$\underbrace{10}_{\equiv 0} \mapsto \underbrace{5}_{\equiv1} \mapsto \underbrace{3}_{\equiv1}\mapsto \underbrace{2}_{\equiv0}\mapsto \underbrace{1}_{\equiv 1} \mapsto \underbrace{1}_{\equiv 1} \mapsto \ldots$$

Writing the remainders as bits from the least to the most significant, this gives an infinite binary string $\ldots1111\ 0110_2$. And one might notice this is the two's complement notation of $-n = -10_{10}$! In fact, considering how $-n_{k+1}$ and $-n_k$ are related by $(2)$,

$$-n_k  = -\left\lceil\frac{n_{k+1}}2\right\rceil = \left\lfloor\frac{-n_{k+1}}2\right\rfloor$$

so applying arithmetic right shift by $1$ bit to $-n_{k+1}$ does give $-n_k$.

Hence both the numerators and denominators in $(1)$ are related by binary right shifts or floored divisions:

$$-\frac{n_{k+1}+2^{k+1}-1}{-n_{k+1}}
\overset{>>1}{\underset{>>1}\longmapsto} -\frac{n_k+2^k-1}{-n_k}$$

---

On the left hand side, if both the numerators and denominators were even, i.e. with last bits $0$, then the two sides would be equal. But the numerators and denominators always have opposite parity, and the $\frac{1+m_{k+1}}{m_{k+1}}$ multiplier is here to round the odd one down to even.

If $n_{k+1}$ is even, then the numerator is odd, so choose $m_{k+1}$ to reduce the numerator by $1$:

$$\begin{align*}
-\frac{n_{k+1}+2^{k+1}-1}{-n_{k+1}}
&= -\frac{n_{k+1}+2^{k+1}-2}{-n_{k+1}}\cdot \frac{n_{k+1}+2^{k+1}-1}{n_{k+1}+2^{k+1}-2}\\
&= -\frac{n_k+2^k-1}{-n_k}\left(1+\frac{1}{n_{k+1}+2^{k+1}-2}\right)
\end{align*}$$

If $n_{k+1}$ is odd, then the denominator is odd, so choose $m_{k+1}$ to reduce the denominator by $1$ (to be more negative):

$$\begin{align*}
-\frac{n_{k+1}+2^{k+1}-1}{-n_{k+1}}
&= -\frac{n_{k+1}+2^{k+1}-1}{-n_{k+1}-1}\cdot \frac{-n_{k+1}-1}{-n_{k+1}}\\
&= -\frac{n_k+2^k-1}{-n_k}\left(1+\frac{1}{n_{k+1}}\right)
\end{align*}$$

This explains why the $m_{k+1}$ appears to be quite different depending on the parity of $n_{k+1}$:

$$m_{k+1} = \begin{cases}
n_{k+1}+2^{k+1}-2,& n_{k+1}\equiv 0 \pmod 2\\
n_{k+1},& n_{k+1}\equiv 1 \pmod 2\\
\end{cases} \tag3$$

To conclude, by considering the recursion step $(1)$ with negated denominators, the choices of $n_k$ and $m_{k+1}$ are related to binary notations and bit shifts. Running the recursion down to $k=0$ gives the last $m_1=n_1$ and a fraction that can be eliminated: $\dfrac{n_0+2^0-1}{n_0} = 1$.

---

Omitted detail on two's complement, which is non-standard:

$$-10_{10} \overset{???}= \ldots1111\ 0110_2 = 2+4+16+32+64+\cdots$$

Either all mentions of bit shifts can be ignored and consider floored division only.

Or a fixed and finite number $L$ can be chosen to be the number of bits for two's complement. $L$ bits should be long enough to represent the numerator $n+2^k-1$ (and hence also the denominator $\pm n$).